# Facebook sdk how to get page like using scoped_user_id

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, version

Im creating a Facebook application which will ask to like page before continue with the app. But after changing Facebook api platform to version 2, I cant get Facebook user id, I get scoped user id instead. Using scoped_user_id i cant get users who liked my page. Heres my code

if ($fb_scope_id){

try {
       $user_like = $facebook->api('/'.$fb_scope_id.'/likes/');

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

```
   $user_like = null;
```

}

}

It returns an empty array. Any solution?

Comment: The user will have to give you user_likes permission before you can check if they liked anything. And if you are going to ask for user_likes you will have to get Facebooks approval first. And we will not grant it if you only use it for like-gating.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. In which cases Facebook will allow me to get user likes for pages? Im developing a game and I can add some feature/award system for like and sharing.

Comment: You are able to get likes on app tab pages. If the user liked the page or not will be in the signed request. And according to Facebook Platform Policy you are not allowed to incentivize sharing.

Comment: Thanks! I got it in the signed request!!!